# How can I hide a bottom tab in the bottom navigation in android. (Landscape mode failed to hide the tab)

Tags: java, android, android-bottomnav

I need to hide center bottom tab in the bottom navigation while launching the app. Here I have tried to remove the tab. It worked in potrait mode, But in the landscape mode, to hide the tab bar in UI.

```
bottomNavigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.schedulers);



<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom"
        android:title="@string/all"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom"
        android:title="@string/my"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/schedulers"
        android:icon="@drawable/schedulers"
        android:title="@string/schedulers"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom"
        android:title="@string/kkk"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bottom"
        android:title="@string/kkkk"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: This should work in any orientation; unless `bottomNavigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.schedulers)` is called under certain conditions; where do you call this?

Comment: I have called this in the MainActivity onNavigationTabSelected() method

Comment: If you want to keep this hidden by default, then call it from a lifecycle method like `onCreate()`; then show it whenever you want

Comment: @Zain After adding it in the oncreate it works fine for me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add it in the onCreate() methods it will works fine and able to hide the tab with the code

```
bottomNavigation.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.schedulers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use listener on navController if using nav component

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.full_screen_destination) {
       toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
       bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
   } else {
       toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
       bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
}
```

[Refrence](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two layout for this app like `portrait` and `landscape`?

If this is the case, immediately delete the landscape file `OR` add the same bottom navigation with very same id. Because I was facing on. this issue lady and finally I resolved it in this way.